# Not able to print some characters(e.g. €) in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I have tried to print some characters(e.g €) on screen dynamically from an external XML. All I got on screen is small rectangle. If I set a €(euro symbol) of a Label's text property in code(i.e. hardcoded), it prints correct on screen. But if I try to set Label's text dynamically, it fails.

Same thing happens with this Russian string "ВЫБЕРИТЕ БАЗОВЫЕ ЦВЕТА". I am using Arial font. Please help. Does it has something to do with the encoding which is written as a first line of Application tag?

Comment: Sounds like your external file doesn't have the right encoding. Can you check what encoding it has?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use it by code. For example:

```
<node>This is euro symbol &#8364;</node>
```

Comment: I have found the solution particularly for this symbol(i.e. euro symbol). Instead of using &#128; , it is better to use  &#8364; as u suggested. But there are other symbols to which are creating problem like the Russian text I've mentioned in main Q. Anyways, thanx for ur suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML file has to have at the beginning:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

and also, file has to be saved with utf-8 encoding:
for example in Notepad++ toolbar  Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8

Also for multilanguage applications You can use flex localizations
have a look:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex_localization_pt1.html

Comment: I request a language XML file to the server whenever a user changes language on the website(when user changes language the whole site gets translated not just the swf), so I cannot put localization properties file & corresponding logic on my end. What my concern is I get the translated labels right(in XML) but when I set it to one of the labels, it doesn't get set as is, it is automatically converted to some codes or some weird characters.

Comment: Does your web page where your swf is embeded has right encoding? Meaning other content except swf looks right?